# Customizing WP-syntax to get custom colors

Tags: css, syntax-highlighting

I downloaded the [WP-syntax](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/) plugin and want to customize it to show a black terminal-style background.

I edited the file `wp-syntax/wp-syntax.css` to

```
.wp_syntax {
  color: #100;
  background-color: black !important;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* IE FIX */
.wp_syntax {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom: expression(this.scrollWidth > this.offsetWidth ? 15 : 0);
  width: 100%;
}

.wp_syntax table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.wp_syntax div, .wp_syntax td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

.wp_syntax .line_numbers {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: black !important;
  color: white !important;
  overflow: visible;
}

/* potential overrides for other styles */
.wp_syntax pre {
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  overflow: visible;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.333;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: black !important;

}
```

However, I am getting a result like

[image]

Most of the text is barely visible. What modifications should I make to the code in order to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugin documentation instructs to [copy style file to theme's directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-syntax/other_notes/), rather than edit it in place (which would make it incompatbile with updates and such).

Other than that this seems like CSS issue and has little to do with WordPress. Some time with Firebug+Firefox or other debug tool usually solves such.